# Refresh redirects to homepage on live server using dynamic routing of next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new to next.js and I am using dynamic routing in one of my project. Everything works fine on local host. When I open the dynamic page it opens up alright, and on refresh the same page appears again after loading up. But when I am hosting it on live domain, then although the page opens up fine, but on refresh it redirects to homepage as if it doesn't recognize the url.
Below is the api call in the dynamic route page.

[Page Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFXh1.png)

[API call in [pid].js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Oh7x.png)

[The call to the dynamic page:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CTpR.png)

I have also tried using getServerSideProps but same issue.
Since this is my first time asking a question at stack overflow so I might have missed some detail. Anyways, any help regarding this matter would be tremondously appreciated.

I think that I have tried almost everything, I just want the dynamic route to render correctly on refresh on live server but I can't seem to find any solution.

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Sure next time i'll make sure that I upload the code but this time the issue has been resolved. Thanks anyways. The issue was with the server that I was deploying to and also because initially I was using getServerSideProps. But static generation solved the problem.